# having trouble implementing notifications to my alarm app

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, alarm

I have created an alarm app that looks similar to ios alarm app and the cells and the tableview also look similar to it . The cells are having 2 things label & switch Button so that when I turn on the button the alarm gets activated at the cell's label time.

There is a `triggerAlarm()` function which keeps track of time and loops through the `items` array which is of type `[Item]()` (`Item` is a class of type `NSManagedObject` which saves the data. It has 2 attributes `time: String` & `isOn: Bool`).

The problem is that the `Timer` method in `viewDidLoad()` is not running through that loop in `triggerAlarm()` func but prints `realTime` . The loop is supposed to compare the `realTime` with items array and call the `notificationTrigger()` func if the `isOn` property is true but its not happening.

Xcode is not showing any error either.

Here is the code :

```
import UIKit
import UserNotifications

class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var realTime  = String()
    var items     = [Item]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge], completionHandler: {didAllow, error in})

    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

        getData()
        tableView.reloadData()

    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return items.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

        let row = items[indexPath.row]

        cell.timeLbl.text   = row.time
        cell.switchBtn.isOn = row.isOn

        cell.callback = { newValue in
            row.isOn = newValue
            (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).saveContext()
        }
        return cell
    }

    func getData() {
        let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
        do {
             items = try context.fetch(Item.fetchRequest())
        }catch{
            print("\(error)")
        }
    }

    func triggerAlarm() {
        realTime = DateFormatter.localizedString(from: Date(), dateStyle: .none, timeStyle: .short)
        print(realTime)
        for i in 0..<items.count {
            if (items[i].time!) == realTime && items[i].isOn == true{
                print(time)
                self.notificationTrigger()
            }else {
                return
            }
        }
    }

    func notificationTrigger() {
        let content      = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        content.title    = "time is up \(time)"
        content.subtitle = "asdf"
        content.body     = "qwer"
        content.badge    = 0

        let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 1, repeats: false)
        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "customNotification", content: content, trigger: trigger)
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request, withCompletionHandler: nil)

    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you calling getData() and tableView.reloadData() in both viewDidLoad and viewWillAppear?  You also have another issue in viewDidLoad.

Comment: i might have copied and pasted instead of cut and paste

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@objc func triggerAlarm() {
    realTime = DateFormatter.localizedString(from: Date(), dateStyle: .none, timeStyle: .short)
    print(realTime)
    for i in 0..<items.count {
        if (items[i].time!) == realTime && items[i].isOn == true{
            print(time)
            self.notificationTrigger()
        }else {
            return
        }
    }
}
```

Here you are using return in else. **So instead of breaking the loop for the current iterartion(I suppose you want to achieve this), it is returning from the whole method call. Instead use:-**

> continue

Or better just omit the else part

```
 @objc func triggerAlarm() {
    realTime = DateFormatter.localizedString(from: Date(), dateStyle: .none, timeStyle: .short)
    print(realTime)
    for i in 0..<items.count {
        if (items[i].time!) == realTime && items[i].isOn == true{
            print(time)
            self.notificationTrigger()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this works thanks but the notification only appears when i scroll the tableview or when open the app from the background